# Who owns the rights to Kingpin?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015, sonys-marvel-universe, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

I used to think that Disney-owned Marvel had a pretty clear-cut claim to Wilson Fisk, featuring him in *Daredevil* since 2015. However, just a few months ago he appeared in *Spider-Verse* (brought to you by Sony), and now I'm not so sure I know who owns him. How can both studios use him?

- Did someone make a deal with someone else, like how Disney let Fox change Negasonic Teenage Warhead's powers in exchange for the rights to use Ego in *Guardians 2*?
- Is it a Quicksilver-style scenario, where Kingpin exists as part of both the rights to Daredevil and the rights to Spider-Man?
- Is this all building up to a Kingpin-Verse movie, in which Peter Parker's multidimensional efforts to bring back Uncle Ben end up uniting Vincent D'Onofrio, Liev Schreiber, Michael Clarke Duncan, and [Kingpig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu4q3.jpg)?

Comment: Daredevil is, of course, some sort of co-production with Netflix, who apparently [have some degree of exclusivity rights on some of the characters therein](https://variety.com/2018/tv/news/defenders-disney-streaming-daredevil-iron-fist-luke-cage-jessica-jones-1203087219/). I'm not super-familiar with the business we call show, but I believe it's fairly common for licensing to be limited to a fairly specific medium, e.g. animated movies.

Comment: Also, AFAIR, Kingpin/Wilson Fisk is not in any of  Sam Raimy's*Spiderman* or Marc Webb's *Amazing Spiderman* movies, so before the *Spider-Verse*, it was not clear that rights to Fisk were "tied" to Spiderman.

Answer (score 1):

Sony made a deal with Fox where Fox paid them for the use of Kingpin in the Daredevil movie.  But when the Daredevil sequel fell through the rights to Daredevil reverted to Marvel.  I think actually the rights to Kingpin may have become a bit scattered.

Comment: Can you can any of this up with evidence?

Answer (score 1):

[It sounds like there's joint ownership currently](https://thedirect.com/article/spider-man-disney-sony-character-rights-issues).

> According to [The Direct](https://thedirect.com/article/spider-man-disney-sony-character-rights-issues), Disney and Sony can't come to a final agreement about the characters of Wilson Fisk (aka The Kingpin) and Jessica Drew (aka Spider-Woman), ostensibly stranding both characters in the Limbo of being co-owned by both studios. That obviously makes use of either character potentially treacherous for each studio, legal-wise, and given the plans that both already have in motion, it's a matter that will need to be addressed sooner, before later.

Following the link they provided, unfortunately, does not provide anything more concrete, although it suggests that Kingpin showing up in both Sony and MCU properties might be either the result of having split animation and live action rights, or based on which supporting characters are allowed to show up (essentially treating Kingpin with Spider-Man as a similar but separate character to Kingpin with Daredevil).

The same situation reportedly exists with Jessica Drew, who started as a Spider-Man character, but is now more strongly paired with The Avengers (although it looks like Sony will introduce her in their upcoming *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse*).

Comment: " Disney and Sony can't come to a final agreement about the characters of Wilson Fisk (aka The Kingpin) and Jessica Drew (aka Spider-Woman), ", Isn't that what applies to every Spider man related character right now, spiderman is owned by sony but appears in mcu, same with venom, morbius and in the near future maybe kraven too(the kraven movie will reveal further details)??

Comment: {nods} I think the fundamental question is, are these characters part of the Spider-Man roster? Kraven almost always stalks Spider-Man and is definitely his villain. Kingpin started as a Spider-man villain, but is now considered to be a *Daredevil* villain. I don't know how specifically the rights contracts were written.